# Size of a list int pointer

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int* T = new int;

    T[0] = 1;
    T[1] = 10;
    T[2] = 100;
    T[3] = 1000;
    T[4] = 10000;
    T[5] = 100000;
    T[6] = 1000000;
    T[7] = 10000000;
    T[8] = 100000000;
    T[9] = 1000000000;

    cout << sizeof(T)/sizeof(int) << "<->" << T[3] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result give me 1 which is incorrect. How can I get the correct number of elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int* T = new int;` allocates space for one int. You can access this `int` through either `T[0]` or `*T`.

`T[1]` is invalid, because you only allocated space for one integer.

Therefore, you have exercised undefined behavior.

You could do `int *T = new int[10];`, which would allocate space for 10 integers on the heap, or `int T[10];` which would allocate space for 10 integers on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

You declared `T` as `int *T`, so if `sizeof(T)/sizeof(int)` evaluates to `1`, it means an `int *` and an `int` both take up the same number of bytes on your system (presuming you're not truncating due to integer division, of course - if you had a weird system where `sizeof(int*)` was `6`, and `sizeof(int)` was `4`, for instance, this would still give you `1`).

If you changed:

```
int* T = new int;
```

to:

```
int T[10];
```

it would work as you appear to expect, and you'd also fix the problem of all those illegal writes to unallocated memory.

Changing to `int *T = new int[10];` would fix your memory write problems, but `sizeof(T)/sizeof(int)` would still evaluate to `1` for you, because `T` is still an `int *`, not an array.